# Error Store NSdata to NsDictonary

Tags: ios, nsdictionary, nsdata

plz help me to parse JSON data. we get response in NSMutable Data. but we cn't take out data in Dictionary.  my jsonDictionary get nil.
this is my Url . i have check on JSON Validator.They show Valid Json output. help....

http://mobileapp.merucabs.com/NearByCab_ETA/GetNearByCabs.svc/rest/nearby?Lat=23.0768222&Lng=72.645732&SuggestedRadiusMeters=5000&CabMaxCount=10

```
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {

   // NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:receivedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    //NSLog(@"Response String is %@",responseString);
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;


jsonDictionary=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:receivedData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
jsonArr=[jsonDictionary objectForKey:@"results"];
  //  NSLog(@"JSONDictionary is %@",jsonDictionary);
[_categoryListTableView reloadData];


}
```

Comment: are you sure you are adding all the data to "recivedData", add the code when you append the data to it

Comment: the json in that url is not valid. check the validity of the json from http://jsonlint.com

Comment: there is not JSON object called results

Comment: Json Validator get valid  json output.

Comment: Can you share the error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the output from your `URL` and I created the New project and Run , the project link is attach [here](https://www.sendspace.com/file/18n9vh)

Comment: if u need assistance I hope with you

Comment: but we can't store data in dictonary . plz help me.

Answer (score 0):

[image]Your json service is returning invalid json. If you inspect the source code of that url you will find

```
<string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">
```

on the header of the file. Make sure the json validity with some validation tools like jsonlint.com

Comment: check out the screenshot please.

Answer (score 0):

remove the line from the result `<stringxmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">`
and try again

```
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {

id jsonDictionary=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:receivedData options:kNilOptions error:nil];
    NSLog(@"JSONDictionary is %@", jsonDictionary);
}
```

Comment: the url is soap method, need to convert XML to NSDictionary